# Styled-components props in dev tools

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I've built the whole example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-rgb-uxfom).

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components/macro";

const Button = styled.button`
  padding: 0.5em;

  ${(props) => {
    if (props.foo === "bar") {
      return `
        color: red;
      `;
    }
  }}
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button foo="bar">Test</Button>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is a simple example of a styled-component using props. With this logic, the color text on the button should be red - and it is. The problem is, under Dev Tools, I don't see any props passed to the `Button` component - it looks like this:

```
<button class="App__Button-sc-1owtrmu-0 gpXrvp">Test</button>
```

I used `styled-component/macro` here to get the actual display name (which is very good), but then if I would have many buttons like that, how would I know (from dev tools) which button has which props passed in? I imagined something like `[...] foo="bar"` in dev tools.

Is there a way to do it in `styled-components`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use react devtools already?

Props can be seen with React dev tools.

Refer to the screenshot below

[image: react-devtools]

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't look there, my fault. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, please accept the answer if it answer your question :) @dabljues

Comment: Had to wait a few seconds ;)